# Is there a way to specify the coroutine context to use for suspend function join points in Spring AOP?

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, spring-aop

Given a Kotlin `suspend` function, I want to create an aspect advice that executes the `suspend` function join point in a coroutine with a specific context. However, I am not sure if this is currently possible?

```kotlin
suspend fun joinPoint() {
  // some logic
}

@Around("execution (* *.joinPoint(..))")
fun advice(pjp: ProceedingJoinPoint): Mono<*> {
  val customContext = CustomContext()
  return mono(customContext) {
    (pjp.proceed() as Mono<*>).awaitFirst()
  }
}
```

Above is a small sample of what I want to achieve. I am using a snapshot of `spring-aop` that addresses the following issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22462.

Ideally, when the join point is executed via the `awaitFirst` method, the custom coroutine context would be available for use within the coroutine. However, it seems as if the join point always executes the coroutine using the context it would have used if it was called without the advice.

My current workaround has been to create the coroutine for the join point with the custom context in the target method itself. However, having to wrap every function I need to execute an advice for is somewhat tedious and I would rather avoid that by centralizing that logic in the advice itself.

```kotlin
val context = CustomContext()

suspend fun joinPoint() = mono(context) {
  // some logic
}

@Around("execution (* *.joinPoint(..))")
fun advice(pjp: ProceedingJoinPoint): Mono<*> {
  return (pjp.proceed() as Mono<*>)
}
```

Is there any way to do this better?

Comment: I don't use Spring, so maybe that's why I'm confused, but it's not clear to me whether `joinPoint` is calling `advice` or vice versa (indirectly), so I don't understand what desired behavior you have. And where in your code are you using some feature of the custom context?

Comment: @Tenfour04 `advice` is calling `joinPoint`. I didn't include the usage of the custom context in my sample, but for my purposes, the custom context is a `ThreadContextElement` that should copy a value from the `ThreadLocal` of the advice into the `ThreadLocal` of the join point.